# How to block uploading a document to SharePoint that already exists? - crm online integration

Tags: c#, sharepoint, dynamics-crm, integration, dynamics-crm-online

Is it possible to block uploading a document (plugin or workflow) when the document is already in SharePoint? A check can be added for the existing regarding and an exception thrown when the document location is being created but it seems that the document is added afterwards to SharePoint regardless.

Comment: any follow up questions ?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamics CRM and SharePoint are two separate products and they have their own execution pipeline for events, so triggers will be different to do validations.

The document location is the only link between CRM and SharePoint, so when the document is uploaded later on that location the trigger that has to be hooked is on SharePoint side and not on CRM side. Plugins/Workflows can only be triggered on CRM database transactions (CRUD for example).

Probably, if the doc upload happens outside CRM context - you can have some logic in regular interval job to iterate through all the docs in that location and mark the CRM doc integrated parent entity record for dupe identified flags.

Or if you have doc upload process inside CRM context - you can hook a CRM custom action for doing that iteration and validation from javascript.